# push even and odd numbers to respective arrays using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm a total beginner and I'm stuck completely on this problem. I'm supposed to use a for loop to traverse an array, pushing odd numbers to the 'odd' array, and evens to the 'even' array.

No numbers are showing up in my arrays when I test the code. I've tried writing it the following two ways:

```
#1

function pickIt(arr){
  var odd=[],even=[];
  //coding here

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      odd.push();
    } else {
      even.push();
    }
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
  
  return [odd,even];


#2

function pickIt(arr){
  var odd=[],even=[];
  //coding here
  for (i = 0; i > 0; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      odd.push();
    } else {
      even.push();
    }
  }
  
  return [odd,even];
}
```

I've checked out some of the solutions to the problem and with respect to the code I've got in #2, the most common solution I guess has the for condition written like this:

```
for (i of arr)
```

and then in the if else statement it's written:

```
odd.push(i);
even.push(i);
```

respectively, but I have no idea how people got there especially concerning the 'for' bit. Can anyone help my brain understand this?

Comment: calling `push` with no arguments doesn't really help. Use `.push(arr[i])`

Comment: Your code is almost there, you just do not push anything into your Arrays (i.e. you call `odd.push()` without any arguments. Instead you need to call `odd.push(arr[i])` to put the current item into the respective Array.

Comment: you need to push arr[i] not the i itself. 2nd function creates an infinite loop. Just get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function pickIt(arr){
  var odd=[],even=[];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      odd.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      even.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(odd);
  console.log(even);
}
  
pickIt([10,5,6,3,24,5235,31]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const odds = [];
const evens = [];

function separateOddEven(arr){
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       updateArray(arr[i]);
    }
 }

 function updateArray(number){
    if (number % 2) {
     odds.push(number);
    }
    else {
      evens.push(number);
    } 
 }

 separateOddEven([7, 3, 4, 1, 5]);
```